# How to freeze UIScrollView scrolling without losing the touch event

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

Is there a way to stop (and start) a UIScrollView's scroll mid-touch, without giving up the in-progress touch event? That is, to still trigger `scrollViewDidScroll` but not animate the scrollview along with the user's finger.

Setting `scrollEnabled` to `false` causes the touch to be lost.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718073/continuous-scrolling-between-uipangesturerecognizer-and-re-enabled-uiscrollview) is essentially what I'm trying to do, but the answer doesn't (seem to) work.

Comment: Another option is to put an invisible scrollview over your real scroll view. In the invisible scrollview's `scrollViewDidScroll:`, if you want the real one to scroll, just do `realScrollView.contentOffset = fakeScrollView.contentOffset;`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to use a UIGestureRecognizer on your view. When you want to intercept the scroll, you would set cancelsTouchesInView to YES, otherwise set it to NO. This might be helpful to you: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIGestureRecognizer/cancelsTouchesInView. Specifically, you'll want to use the SwipeGestureRecognizer: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UISwipeGestureRecognizer